# ArgParse: ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>

Tags: python

I would like to run my code with argument in command line, but I'am getting error. I use argparse first time and I don't know where is the mistake.

command:

```
python3 malytest1111.py --csv "/home/gis/0418_GML_OT_BUBD_A.csv"
```

code:

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--csv', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()   


df = pd.read_csv(args.csv)
df = df[['lokalnyId', 'wersjaId', 'x_katIstnienia', 'nazwa', 'x_kod', 
         'funOgolnaBudynku', 'funSzczegolowaBudynku',
         'liczbaKondygnacji', 'x_aktualnoscG', 'x_aktualnoscA'
         , 'kodKst', 'zabytek', 'x_skrKarto',
         'koniecWersjiObiektu', 'geometry']]
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is `--budcsv`?

Comment: Is it not name of argument?

Comment: It is either `-csv` or `--budcsv`. I think you should remove `--budcsv` and use `pd.read_csv(args.csv)`.

Comment: for two different arguments, add two different options

Comment: @anurag No, he's not. It's not a tuple. `(parser.parse_args(), ) ` is.

Comment: I have just edited my post but I'am still getting an error.

Comment: `parser.add_argument('--csv', nargs='+', help='description')` and `parser.add_argument('--budcsv', nargs='+', help='description')`

Comment: @datasciencebegginer how are you executing at prompt?
`python3 malytest1111.py --csv "/home/gis/0418_GML_OT_BUBD_A.csv"`

Comment: @anurag Like you said. python3 malytest1111.py --csv "/home/gis/0418_GML_OT_BUBD_A.csv"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) -

Try this:

```py
import argparse
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--csv', nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()   

    #print(args.csv)

    df = pd.read_csv(args.csv[0])
    
    print(df)
```

Run as:

```
python3 malytest1111.py --csv "/home/gis/0418_GML_OT_BUBD_A.csv"
```

Comment: `args.csv` returns a list when `nargs='+'`! We need to get the actual path via indexing!

Comment: Just to add, it doesn't matter whether you use `('-csv', nargs='+')` or `('--csv', nargs='+')` in this case!